# I have two bootable flash drives with different linux distros installed on each, both started malfunctioning within a 24 hour time frame

Tags: arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, live-usb, bootable

I could use some detective work.

I've taken to installing linux on USB drives. I've managed to break Windows a couple of times while repartitioning my main drive.

I've had a 128 Gb USB drive I've been using to boot into Ubuntu Linux 22 for at least eighteen months. I've had no major issues; however, when I boot my device, I need to open a boot manager and select my flash drive before proceeding, which opens my Grub bootloader and permits me to proceed.

About a week ago, I decided I could use more space, so I installed Garuda Linux KDE Dr460nized on a 1 Tb USB drive. It seemed like ample space and the partitioning went fine. I've been using it at work without any issues. It's behaved like Arch Linux with training wheels for me. It used a separate bootloader, which also only seemed to work if I opened my device's boot manager, before starting the Linux installation's boot manager.

The other day, I managed to boot my flash drive containing Garuda Linux on a work computer, which was AWESOME, because it meant I could benefit from the machine's hardware while still retaining admin privileges. I shut down the machine and plugged it back into my own. I opened the device to find it had not been shut down completely. Now that the flash drive was plugged back in, I didn't see why it couldn't proceed safely, so I proceeded to open the lock screen and continued using the device with nonchalance. I got a few unusual pop-ups I didn't bother noting and proceeded to shut down my machine when I my pop-ups persisted.

When I booted the flash drive again, I found myself with a terminal interface which read

```
[FAILED] Failed to mount /sysroot.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Initrd Root File System
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Mountpoints Configured in the Real Root.

Generating "/run/initramps/rdsosreport.txt"

Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue"
```

etc. I can access a /bin/sh shell in the terminal interface.

I've looked at a few solutions and I'll be doing some reading tonight, but I'm not looking for an immediate solution for this error while booting. I'm more interested in what followed. Within 24 hours, I decided to revert back to my USB drive with Ubuntu installed to get some work done. I've booted into the OS safely a couple of times in the past 24 hours, but it's started misbehaving in the past hour. During booting, I notice the output

```
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD AutoFS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PPAC Service responder socket.
```

etc.
Another "Regular background program processing daemon" routine runs.
But the boot loader fails at

```
[FAILED] NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
```

Booting continues

```
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager
```

Then the system stops. I have a cursor that continues blinking, but nothing interesting happens.

Because the Ubuntu flash drive seemed to work fine for over a year and started having issues booting within the same 24-hour window as the Garuda flash drive, I'm tempted to believe the issues have a common cause, even though the errors I am getting while booting look very different.

I had a suspicion the issue was with my computer, so I tried booting my device on my work computer, I find myself with the same issue I have on my personal PC.

Windows saunters on, unperturbed by my USB shenanigans, so I doubt there is anything seriously wrong with my device.

The only change I've made to the BIOS recently was switching off secure boot for the Garuda linux OS.

It's always possible two of my flash drives happened to be corrupted within the same short period, but I figured somebody here would have some insight if that is not the case.

Comment: Update: the issue with Ubuntu turned out to be a compatibility problem with some of the software I use which talks with those pesky Nvidia drivers. I've had to solve problems with these several times in the past, my money is on a spurious temporal association now

Comment: when you are in emergency mode, and the system has told you `Generating "/run/initramps/rdsosreport.txt"` ... did you view that file? It's not clear from your question if you have

Comment: I've had an unsavory development on the Garuda Linux side. The contents of the *txt are extensive, so I'll need to copy it to a USB. The tricky bit is my system stops responding to keystrokes after thirty seconds to three minutes. It'd be instructive to dig through the report, but I'm tempted to pursue a solution described here: https://kpj.github.io/linux/RescuingABrokenSystem.html this solution seems as educational as deciphering the rdsosreport.txt and a great deal less daunting. I can still get the file either way, I'd just need to find my USB's path in 30 seconds